# Change Linux message queue permission at run-time

Tags: linux, permissions, runtime, message-queue

A message queue is implemented using "mq_open" function with default permission. I know that we can set permission of the message queue using the mode argument. But once we compiled the system is there any possibility of changing the permission of the message queue (during the runtime) using some other linux command, other than compiling the binary again ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the following:

```
   int mq_setattr(mqd_t mqdes, struct mq_attr *newattr,
                    struct mq_attr *oldattr);
```

> mq_setattr() sets message queue attributes using information supplied in the mq_attr structure pointed to by newattr.
>
> **The only attribute that can be modified is the  setting  of the O_NONBLOCK flag in mq_flags.**
>
> The other fields in newattr are ignored.  If the oldattr field is not NULL, then the buffer that it points to is used to return an mq_attr structure that contains the same information that is returned by mq_getattr().

Unfortunately, you can see that it's rather limited.

Comment: Fabien .. my Requirement is to change the permission during the runtime.. without recompiling the application using some API ...

Comment: I don't think you can, as stated by the documentation of the API. However, what you could do is create different MQ with different permissions, and switch from one to another according to your needs.